# Steric factors greater than 1 or less than 0?

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics

From my understanding, the steric factor accounts for the relative orientation required by reactants in order to react in collision theory. This implies that steric factors should probably always be below 1 and above 0, since the relative orientation logically should always be a limiting factor, but below 0 or equal to 0 would mean that the reaction cannot take place.

However, my textbook, as a thinking point, asked if there could be a case where the steric factor is more than 1. Specifically, the example it gave was the harpoon mechanism between potassium and the iodine molecule.

My question is, can the steric factor be above 1 or less than 0, and how does that apply to the harpoon mechanism?

Comment: Can you actually have a steric factor less than 0? That would imply a negative rate.

Comment: I dont know, thats what Im asking.

Comment: Harpoon reactions have a steric factor greater than one.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harpoon_reaction

Comment: A negative steric factor would imply a negative rate constant which is not possible. In a harpoon reaction a factor greater than 1 simply means that bigger cross-sections are found to be necessary, compared to those normally used,  to fit experiment to theory. Usually there are so many approximations in transition state theory ( geometry of transitions state, activation energy, bond frequencies, friction due to solvent) that steric factors are added as a sort of loose way of fitting calculation to experiment when one has nothing more concrete.

Comment: I have also read (on Wikipedia [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_theory#Steric_factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_theory#Steric_factor), but without reference indicated ) that a greater than 1 steric factor can happen due to the solvent, making so that "several collisions can take place in a single encounter". I don't know how this phenomenon should be balanced with the underestimated cross-section mentioned by @porphyrin.

Comment: @The Quark , yes this is the sort of thing that is often stated to rationalise results, but the evidence for such a thing occurring is weak if non-existent. How could one actually measure this for example? Especially as in any reaction with a reasonable activation barrier many thousands to millions of collisions occur before reaction actually occurs.